# Set parameter values according to other parameter value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to setup parameter values according to other parameter value like following in stored procedure

```
DECLARE @secndvalues NCHAR(1);

IF (@firstvalue = 'Con')
BEGIN
    SET @secndvalues = 'R';
END
ELSE IF (@firstvalue = 'Tin')
BEGIN
    SET @secndvalues = 'N';
END
```

but it seems like it's not working with the second condition which is `ELSE IF (@firstvalue = 'Tin')`. How can I do this properly?

Comment: [Works for me...](http://rextester.com/UIFQ53735)

Comment: what is the datatype of @firstvalue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was `@firstvalue` length too short keep its values, since that `@firstvalue` value getting null, therefor `@secndvalues` values can't setup , now problem sorted

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but a `case` seems simpler:

```
DECLARE @secndvalues NCHAR(1);
SET @secondvalues = (CASE WHEN @firstvalue = 'Con' THEN 'R'
                          WHEN @firstvalue = 'Tin' THEN 'N'
                          ELSE @secondvalues
                     END);
```

Comment: or even simpler: `CASE  @firstvalue WHEN 'Con' THEN 'R' WHEN 'Tin THEN 'N' END`